# How to findout if paper trading or real trading at IBKR

Tags: vb.net, trading, interactive-brokers

Like many others at Interactive-Brokers I have an account for papertrading and another for trading with real money.

Using VB I can send orders for Trader Workstation (TWS) to IB and receive info about the status of these orders.

As I don't want to mix up orders for papertrading and trading with real money I want my software to identify if I'm logged in with my papertrading account or with my account for trading with real money.

How can I distinguish using VB and the API ?

Answer (score 2):

Your paper and real accounts have different ids.

TWS will automatically send a list of managed accounts once the connection is established. The list can also be fetched at any other time via

> client.reqManagedAccts()

See https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/managed_accounts.html

In my case the paper account starts with "DU" while the real account starts with "U", so I simply check for the initial letters and throw a warning or exit.

The string 'accountsList' is a comma-separated string of account ids, unless you have multiple accounts there should only be a single string received.

```
 Public Sub managedAccounts(accountsList As String) Implements IBApi.EWrapper.managedAccounts

      ' Split the string on the comma character.
      Dim ids As String() = accountsList.Split({","c})

      ' Loop through result strings with For Each.
      For Each id As String In ids
           If id.StartsWith("DU") Then
                MsgBox("Paper account")
           ElseIf id.StartsWith("U") Then
                MsgBox("Real account")
           End If
      Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that at https://youtu.be/TWzITCzRN7k already but it depends on a naming convention of IB. For now it is a workaround but it would be logical to have a boolean function or variable supplied by the API.

Comment: Correct. I had a look through the API source and couldn't find any hint of TWS exposing that info to the API. Seem the only other solution is to request it as a feature https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=2493

Comment: I connect to IB with         signal = New EReaderMonitorSignal() 
        ibClient = New EClientSocket(Me, signal) 
        ibClient.eConnect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 0) and noticed that ibclient.reqManagedAccts() doesn't always provide the accountname if TWS has been started before VS2022 (by putting a MsgBox in managedAccounts). I also tried ibClient.reqAccountSummary(reqid, group, tags) In the API_REFERENCE_GUIDE I found that nextValidId indicates connection is OK. I had to put a loop checking idOrderIB > 0 after eConnect to make it work always. Do you have this as well? Can you improve test?

Comment: I have not been able to replicate that. Every time I connect or run ibclient.reqManagedAccts() I receive the managedAccounts callback.
Checking logs shows the same, I always start TWS first since my app connects on Form_Load. 
The only thing I could suggest is making sure you are using the latest API and TWS versions.

Comment: To add, instead of checking idOrderIB in a loop it would be preferable to use the "Public Sub nextValidId(orderId As Integer) Implements EWrapper.nextValidId" callback which occurs when the connection is ready. 
If the issues persist post a minimal example so we have a concrete base to troubleshoot from.